# Regarding error log of "invalid bearer token, service account token is not valid yet" on kube-apiserver-controller-master

Tags: kubernetes

all, is here anybody has the experience of solving apiserver "invalid bearer token" errors?

I am a newbie to kubernetes cluster, recently i deployed a trial cluster on my working LAN. the version matrix is like below:

```
-   CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
-   GO version go1.20.4
-   Docker-CE 24.0.2
-   cri-dockerd 0.3.2: CRI Interface for Docker Application Container Engine
-   Containerd Containerd.io 1.6.21
-   kube-apiserver:v1.27.2
-   kube-controller-manager:v1.27.2
-   kube-scheduler:v1.27.2
-   kube-proxy:v1.27.2
-   pause:3.9/pause:3.6 (manually deployed 3.6 locally, not sure why need this.)
-   etcd:3.5.7-0
-   coredns:v1.10.1
-   Flannel 0.22
```

cluster running environment is like below:

```
# kubectl get service -A

NAMESPACE        NAME                                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
chan-namespace   nodeport-service-chan-nginx-development             NodePort    10.6.228.232   <none>        80:32577/TCP             8d
chan-namespace   nodeport-service-chan-nginx-development-portbased   NodePort    10.6.111.58    <none>        8080:31529/TCP           8d
chan-namespace   service-nodeport-blog-access                        NodePort    10.6.100.85    <none>        888:31695/TCP            3d6h
chan-namespace   service-nodeport-blog-mysql                         NodePort    10.6.244.105   <none>        3308:30006/TCP           7h21m
chan-namespace   service-nodeport-expose                             NodePort    10.6.66.244    <none>        8081:30001/TCP           5h48m
default          kubernetes                                          ClusterIP   10.6.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                  9d
kube-system      kube-dns                                            ClusterIP   10.6.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   9d

# kubectl get pod -A
NAMESPACE        NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS         AGE
chan-namespace   blog-access-node-5d6b6b9584-dshzl           1/1     Running   6 (48m ago)      3d2h
chan-namespace   blog-mysql-76cd95c4c8-qvvph                 1/1     Running   0                3h55m
chan-namespace   busybox                                     1/1     Running   0                56m
chan-namespace   nginx-deployment-chan-57d84f57dc-88tr4      1/1     Running   2 (48m ago)      12h
chan-namespace   nginx-deployment-chan-57d84f57dc-dtffm      1/1     Running   2 (48m ago)      12h
chan-namespace   nginx-deployment-chan-57d84f57dc-tztpg      1/1     Running   7 (48m ago)      4d13h
kube-flannel     kube-flannel-ds-gg6dc                       1/1     Running   3 (5h14m ago)    2d2h
kube-flannel     kube-flannel-ds-nn4x5                       1/1     Running   17 (48m ago)     9d
kube-flannel     kube-flannel-ds-tdttg                       1/1     Running   3 (5h14m ago)    2d2h
kube-system      coredns-7c987b59d4-62b6d                    1/1     Running   1 (48m ago)      3h55m
kube-system      coredns-7c987b59d4-w9s7x                    1/1     Running   1 (48m ago)      3h55m
kube-system      etcd-controller-master                      1/1     Running   18 (48m ago)     9d
kube-system      kube-apiserver-controller-master            1/1     Running   18 (48m ago)     9d
kube-system      kube-controller-manager-controller-master   1/1     Running   18 (48m ago)     9d
kube-system      kube-proxy-2tsff                            1/1     Running   11 (5h14m ago)   9d
kube-system      kube-proxy-9268z                            1/1     Running   18 (48m ago)     9d
kube-system      kube-proxy-t57jz                            1/1     Running   3 (5h14m ago)    2d2h
kube-system      kube-scheduler-controller-master            1/1     Running   18 (48m ago)     9d

# kubectl get cs
Warning: v1 ComponentStatus is deprecated in v1.19+
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE                         ERROR
scheduler            Healthy   ok                              
controller-manager   Healthy   ok                              
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health":"true","reason":""}   

# kubectl get ns
NAME              STATUS   AGE
chan-namespace    Active   9d
default           Active   9d
kube-flannel      Active   9d
kube-node-lease   Active   9d
kube-public       Active   9d
kube-system       Active   9d

# NTP crontd running info on each cluster node is like below:
# crontab -l
*/5 * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate -u time1.aliyun.com >>/var/log/ntp-udpate-chan.log  2>&1
```

the API-Sever Podset always prompts error info like below:

```
E0614 13:16:29.609061       1 authentication.go:70] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="[invalid bearer token, service account token is not valid yet]"
E0614 13:16:37.014138       1 authentication.go:70] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="[invalid bearer token, service account token is not valid yet]"
```

the Flannel Podset always prompts error info like below:

```
0614 13:13:26.346353       1 reflector.go:140] github.com/flannel-io/flannel/pkg/subnet/kube/kube.go:487: Failed to watch *v1.Node: failed to list *v1.Node: Unauthorized
W0614 13:14:11.331341       1 reflector.go:424] github.com/flannel-io/flannel/pkg/subnet/kube/kube.go:487: failed to list *v1.Node: Unauthorized
E0614 13:14:11.331361       1 reflector.go:140] github.com/flannel-io/flannel/pkg/subnet/kube/kube.go:487: Failed to watch *v1.Node: failed to list *v1.Node: Unauthorized
```

the CoreDNS alwyas prompts error info like below:

```
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: failed to list *v1.Namespace: Unauthorized
[ERROR] plugin/kubernetes: pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.Namespace: failed to list *v1.Namespace: Unauthorized
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: failed to list *v1.Service: Unauthorized
[ERROR] plugin/kubernetes: pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: Unauthorized
```

Any body could help me to solve these errors? any hint is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is that your machine's time is synchronized from the wrong time in the future to the correct time now.
You can restart the kubelet of the affected node：

```
systemctl restart kubelet
```

more info in [my blog serviceAccountToken](https://zhangguanzhang.github.io/2024/02/06/serviceAccountToken-valid/)